# Compass error: Webkit only supports pixels for the start and end stops for radial gradients

Tags: css, webkit, sass, gradient, compass

I'm having a problem in my Backbone app. I'm using sass and compass.

When I try to build the app, I get this error:

Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
  warning Webkit only supports pixels for the start and end stops for radial gradients. Got: 70%

My background image (a texture image file) is also being compiled to 100%, which is causing all  of my textures to look large and grainy.

What do I need to do to ensure that I do not get this error?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't find any references for Webkit only supporting pixels for start/end stops, but its just a warning not an error.  Is there not a way to tell your builder to only halt on errors?

Answer (score 1):

This warning only applies to really old Webkit browsers, so it can safely be ignored for recent versions of Chrome and Safari.